# Error Code: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

create a function in mysql,when a function is call i got  "Error Code: 1241
 Operand should contain 1 column(s)" how to solve the error

```
drop function if exists age;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION age (Dob date,Username varchar(30))

RETURNS INT

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

DECLARE age int;

set age=(SELECT *, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Dob)   FROM per_det where username=Username);

return age;

END;//

delimiter ;

select * from per_det;
```

i got  "Error Code: 1241

Operand should contain 1 column(s)" how to solve the error

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting multiple columns in the `SET` subquery, while `age` expects to be a single `INT` value.  You don't want the `*` here:

```
set age=(SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Dob)   FROM per_det where username=Username);
```